# Change header's name for \section*

Tags: header-footer

I'm using the `article` class and I would like to know how it is possible to change the name in the header of a specific page.

I have the following sections in my article:

```
\section{Introduction}
\section{Codes}
\section{Implementation}
\section*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Conclusion}
```

The section named "Conclusion" isn't numbered. The problem is that the header in this section is the same as the previous section which is in this case the section "Implementation". I would like to know how it is possible to change the header's name "Implementation" to "Conclusion" in this page.

My article has the following settings:

```
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\rhead{\leftmark}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Thank you though.

Comment: It's easier to do with the `titleps` package, that comes with `titlesec`, instead of `fancyhdr`: it has a `\sectiontitle` command that stores the current section title, whether numbered or not, that you can use on defining a page style in the place of \leftmatk/\rightmark.

Comment: @Zombie: "Doesn't seem to work" doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `article`, which has `\section`s as the main sectional unit, you need to make a small adjustment to the suggestions in [Want `\section*` to change the page header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56711/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}% Right footer
\rhead{\leftmark}$ Right header

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Codes}\lipsum[1-25]
\section{Implementation}\lipsum[1-25]
\section*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Conclusion}
\markboth{CONCLUSION}{}% This updates \leftmark
\lipsum[1-25]

\end{document}
```